# Best text encoding for parallel work on Mac and Windows with umlauts in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I am currently working with R with a big group of students. R-Scripts are shared a lot between the students and the instructors and errors concerning the encoding of the scripts occur a lot, especially while umlauts (ä,ü,ö) are being used in the scripts.

Which are best saving options I can tell students/tutors to use on both Mac and Windows to reduce the amount of errors? UTF-8 or something else? Is it enough to change the encoding on R or does it have to be changed on the computers as well?

One solution would be to not use umlauts at all, but the work contains statistical analysis, where the umlauts are pretty common.

Best regards

Comment: UTF8 and Mac may need configuring. Windows strings are Unicode already. *Linux/Unix* applications use whatever encoding is set at the machine level though, which means that a) you need to ensure UTF8 is set and b) when those applications are carelessly ported to Windows they misbehave, as they act as ASCII applications. R was such an application but they've fixed such problems.

Comment: *R Packages* especially those that work with files are another problem. Most accept an encoding parameter to read files that aren't in the OS's codepage but some don't. That's a package bug that needs to be fixed. If you have to use them with mixed-codepage content, oops.

Comment: The reason for all this was that Linux/Unix was built with servers in mind. On a server, all applications use the same locale settings. Applications launched interactively are expected to either use the server's or user's locale settings. This way applications wouldn't have to be rewritten to support Unicode. Nobody though that eg someone in Germany would have to crunch data containing Cyrillic or Chinese text.

Comment: Like beer bottle sales in Germany, Ukraine and Russia. Turns out that the same glassworks factories sell to all of them, and of course each sales branch will use their country's encoding for sales reports because nobody complained before

Comment: So UTF8 is the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, but! You could still face problems if people set their editors to save files using a different encoding. R Studio for example [doesn't store scripts as UTF8 on Windows unless explicitly configured](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding), but at least it asks you which encoding to use if it detects non US-ASCII characters. BTW I found those problems working with RStudio versions before 0.93, so I may be overreacting

Comment: Thank you very much, I switched everything to UTF-8 and I am going to test if that works properly for the students as well.